# HTML/CSS - Drop Down menu's not cascading

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

Currently working on creating a dropdown menu and while styling I seem to have broken the actual dropdown functionality of the menu where the rest of the buttons don't drop down, or only a few do and I'm racking my brain trying to fix it and making no progress.

Am wanting the button to drop vertically if possible, so for instance if you highlight Requests you get:

- Submit New Request
- Open Requests
- Closed Requests

Any assistance to help rectify would be greatly appreciated.

Apologies if the code is a little messy, it is an early work in progress with some tidying left to do!

```css
<html><head><style>body {
  font: normal normal bold 16px trebuchet ms;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.nv {
  background: #4d9fb1;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nv a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
}

.snv {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.snv .snvbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.nv a:hover,
.snv:hover .snvbtn {
  background: white;
  color: #3B7A8B;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
}

.snv-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #4d9fb1;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}

.snv-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.snv-content a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #3B7A8B;
}

.snv:hover .snv-content {
  display: block;
}

.nv li {
  border-right: 3px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nv li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.nv li>a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 19px;
}

</style></head>
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="nv">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <div class="snv">
      <li><button class="snvbtn">Requests
          </button></li>
      <div class="snv-content">
        <li><a href="#company">Submit New Request</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Open Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#careers">Closed Requests</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="snv">
      <li><button class="snvbtn">Proactive Maintenance</button></li>
      <div class="snv-content">
        <li><a href="#bring">Outstanding Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#deliver">Completed Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#package">Your Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#express">Export Report</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="snv">
      <li><button class="snvbtn">Admin Tools</button></li>
      <div class="snv-content">
        <li><a href="#link1">VPN Activity</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2">Backup Reporting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link3">Asset List</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link4">Licence Management</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#contact">Your Profile</a></li>
  </div>



</body>

</html>

</div>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML markup around `li` tags is invalid. The `li` tag must be contained in a parent element of `ul`, `ol`, or `menu` (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li ), and fixing this structure might be the good first step. Then, see this CSS Tricks article that explains HTML/CSS structure for hover dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code snippets style in your HTML code.

1. **Navigation Menu Snippet**

   ```
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <li> <a href="#"> Hyperlink 1  </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Hyperlink 2  </a>
            <ul class="sub1">
                <li> <a href="#"> Hyperlink 2.1  </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Hyperlink 2.2  </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Hyperlink 2.3  </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Hyperlink 3  </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Hyperlink 4  </a></li>
    </ul>
   ```

**2) Navigation menu style sheet HTML snippet**

//Rules for writing navigation menu snippet

```
          <style>             
                                    
               ul#navmenu, ul.sub1 {
                    list-style-type: none;
               }
               ul#navmenu li {
                    outline: 1px;
                    width: 125px;
                    text-align:center;
                    position: relative;
                    float: left;
                    margin-right: 4px;    
               }
               ul#navmenu a {
                    text-decoration:none;
                    display:block;
                    width:125px;
                    height:25px;
                    line-height: 25px;
                    border:1px;
                    border-radius:5px;
              }   
       </style>
```

From the above, the HTML code snippets, replace the hyperlinks according to your requirement, and run it again. Make sure you give proper class names for every tag and keep it the same in the CSS file, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

All mater of position absolute

try the following

```css
body {
  font: normal normal bold 16px trebuchet ms;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.nv {
  background: #4d9fb1;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nv a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
}

.snv {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.snv .snvbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.nv a:hover,
.snv:hover .snvbtn {
  background: white;
  color: #3B7A8B;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
}

.snv-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background: !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4d9fb1), to(#2f626d));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d9fb1, #2f626d);
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 9;
  color: white;
}

.snv-content a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.snv-content a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #3B7A8B;
}
.snv-content li {
    width: 100%;
}
.snv:hover .snv-content {
     display: block;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 50px;
    left: 49%;
    background: grey;
    z-index: 99999;
   width:30%;
}

.nv li {
  border-right: 3px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* transition: initial; */
}

.nv li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.nv li>a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 19px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nv">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <div class="snv">
      <li><button class="snvbtn">Requests
          </button></li>
      <div class="snv-content">
        <li><a href="#company">Submit New Request</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">Open Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#careers">Closed Requests</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>

    
  </div>
```